# Android: reset if reopened after launching external Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My app requires location services to be enabled.

I wrote a loader `Activity` that verifies the different providers, and launches the system settings interface if something needs reconfiguring, much like Google Maps does.

```
Intent goToSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(goToSettings);
```

Problem is, if the user navigates away without finishing the settings panel, it's left at the top of the `Activity` stack and shows up again when the app is brought to foreground (on relaunch, maybe in other scenarios).

How can I "detach" the system settings from my app? I tried combining flags and launch modes, but I can't get it working.

Comment: Doesn't calling `finish()` after starting the "system settings" activity, work?

Comment: No, it finishes the loader `Activity` but the system settings panel remains on top of the stack

Comment: Ok. Can you post some code?

Comment: What do you mean by "detach the system settings from my app"? What is the behavior that you desire?

Comment: I want the user to land back in my Activity when he relaunches or refocuses the app, NOT the system settings panel. I want the settings panel to exist separately. As if to say, I want to `fork` before I `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); to launch the external intent as a separate task.